# Swift Realm, write into database not working in appdelegate when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, realm

in my app when receive a new push notification I want to insert some data into my Realm database, but the problem is if app be in background data not write in database but if user touch notification in notification bar then everything works fine!

below is my code for insert data into Realm DB:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write() {
                                
    let notif = NotificationDBModel()

    notif.id = id
                                
    if let title = data["title"] {
       notif.title = title as! String
    }
                                
    if let content = data["content"] {
       notif.content = content as! String
    }
                                
    if let date = data["date"] {
       notif.date = date as! String
    }
                                
    realm.add(notif)

}
```

Comment: The code in your question works fine for me. That indicates you're got an issue somewhere outside of that code. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Oh, your `NotificationDBModel` may be an issue but we don't know what that looks like. Can you update the question with that object?

Answer (score 0):

The Realm insertion code looks fine, Do check whether you have enable the `Background modes` within `signing & Capabilities`

Comment: Yes I enabled `Background fetch` , `Remote notifications`, `Background processing`, but didn't work, I set break point and `try! realm.write() {` not working.